# Slim framework won't route more than a few GET routes

Tags: php, slim

I can't get Slim to give me a response for more than a couple of GET routes: Here's my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->config(array(
   'templates.path' => './templates'
));

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('landing.php');
});

$app->get('/about', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('about.php');
});

$app->get('/signup', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('signup.php');
});

$app->get('/dashboard', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('dashboard.php');
});

$app->run();

?>
```

It works fine when I run `localhost:8888`, Slim renders `landing.php` normally, if I type in `localhost:8888/index.php/about` it renders the about page, but as soon as I type in `localhost:8888/index.php/signup` or `localhost:8888/index.php/dashboard` it fails with a 404 error. Any help would be appreciated.

Just to clarify, I haven't set up URL rewriting on my server (gave me other sorts of errors), and the files that I'm trying to render DO indeed exist.

Comment: 404 means file not found. signup.php or dashboard.php really exist into directory

Comment: Just edited the post above to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing the wrong file, sorry SO, my bad.